# How to handle UserControl events

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol containing 3 empty minutes textboxes named txtMorningMinutes, txtAfternoonMinutes and txtCapacityMinutes. This UserControl is repeated 2 times as Saturday and Sunday in a Webform with Save button outside UserControl and inside Webform.

Now there is a condition that user should enter a value less than that of txtCapacityMinutes for which the value is coming from database. Lets say the value of txtCapacityMinutes is 60.

Now the user enters 10 in Saturday morning textbox called txtMorningMinutes and saves the data. It will be persisted to the database.

Now the user enters 70 in Saturday morning textbox called txtMorningMinutes and tries to save data. Before saving the data in OnTextChanged of txtMorningMinutes, we need to check whether newly entered data is less than that of 60 which is txtCapacityMinutes. Because newly entered data 70 is greater than 60, we need to revert it back to 10.

The TextChanged event is something like below

```
protected void txtMorningMinutes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Where should I preserve the initial value of 10 in UserControl. If it is stored in Page_Load event of UserControl, it will be repeated 2 times i.e., for Saturday UserControl and Sunday UserControl. So, I need know about where to store previous value of txtMorningMinutes.Text i.e., 10 and apply the condition whenever necessary in OnTextChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user focuses the textbox you can save a copy of the relevant variables before they are manipulated. When the user clicks the save button you can perform your checks and rollback to the saved variables values if needed.

Comment: In which event should I store the data of the relevant variable. And how can I distinguish with the event is raised for Saturday or Sunday user controls.

Comment: Validation in client side is also OK with me.

Answer (score -1):

```
static string previousValue = "";
protected void Page_Load()
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
       previousValue = "5";
  }
}

protected void txtMorningMinutes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(Convert.ToInt32(txtMorningMinutes.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacityMinutes.Text))
{
 txtMorningMinutes.Text = Convert.ToInt32(txtMorningMinutes.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacityMinutes.Text)
}
}
```

Comment: you should store the relevant data in _TextChanged event only, then you can use that value wherever you want